# Access Gmail behind Firewall Java

Tags: java, gmail, imap, firewall

I have a problem with access the gmail from my working area. This is my **[code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6375181/)**. It works in my home when network settings are default. The main problem is, in the working area there is more security on computers and network like firewalls etc..

I have to find a solution for run this script behind the firewall. Closing the firewall is not a permanent solution.

Also I added the error message to the below. Any help is appreciated.

```
  `com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: imap.gmail.com, 993; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:672)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at unreadmails.MailReader.<init>(MailReader.java:23)
    at unreadmails.MailReader.main(MailReader.java:12)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:297)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:229)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:116)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:115)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:689)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:638)
    ... 4 more`
```

Comment: Which firewall are you using?

Comment: I think its a problem with port not with proxy try to change port to 587

Comment: Trend micro OfficeScan Real-Time
Matrix42
lots of staff setup in computer, I am new at this computer.

Comment: @ankit When I add this line to code `props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");`
I take this error. [ERROR](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6375206/)

Comment: @BatuhanBardak can you tell the host name

Comment: see this link http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/QqVyRkEcs_I%5B1-25-false%5D

Comment: You will have to /configure/ your firewall to allow connections through port 993 to imap.gmail.com.